# Changing identical types in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml

Suppose I have a function `list_fun : int_list -> string list` and in that function I use a `StringSet` that I define as module `StringSet = Set.Make(String)`. I try to have the function return `Set.elements s` and get a `string list` but instead I get a `StringSet.elt list` which is supposed to be the same thing, as the `StringSet`'s `type t = string`

How do you make OCaml understand that these types are identically defined? I have several cases where I have come across this issue as I have started using the OCaml standard library functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml already knows that they are identically defined - unless you're doing something strange to hide the types behind an abstraction, it will treat a `StringSet.elt list` and `string list` as the same type.